# Enable USB Legacy Support from Ubuntu

Tags: usb, laptop, bios

I have a laptop with only USB keyboard. I created vicious circle - can't use usb keyboard, because usb legacy disabled; can't enable usb legacy, because usb keyboard doesn't work in bios

I heard somewhere, that windows can automatically rewrite this option to be enabled, but i cant install windows
And i know flashing bios enables it, but i cant,because it flashes from usb
Also i tried to reset bios settings by removing battery(of laptop and of motherboard) for many hours

Do i have any chances to enable usb legacy support (without buying integrated keyboard)?

p.s. my MB is Quanta TWH, bios - InsydeH2O

Comment: If your MB has a PS2 keyboard port, you'll probably have to use it and connect a PS2 keyboard to do what you want. I'm not 100% sure that enabling USB legacy (if it even exists on your MB) will solve your USB/BIOS problem anyway. Have you checked for a BIOS update for your MB? Cheers, Al

Comment: no, MB does not have PS2, because it's laptop. I know enabling USB legacy solve my problem, because i used it before. And i cant update my BIOS because it needs windows or usb(if dos).There is no flasher for my MB for linux

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I missed the laptop vs motherboard part. I now assume that your laptop's integral keyboard is defective/missing. I've seen some GRUB menus that allow BIOS access, but yours may not be one of them. I have no other ideas for you. Good luck. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume missing details. You did not state what steps you took to delete the legacy USB.

I assume you have a live installation DVD which has a little option of a look at Linux which is there so a Windows user will fall in love and switch.

It can also be used as a rescue disc. (I have rescue discs but I haven't used one.)  I don't mean reinstall.  You have not stated how the USB legacy was disabled.  Again, I'm going to guess.  It may be a file in **/etc/modprobe.d/** with a **.conf** extension.  Look thru those and see if you can find the one the locks out the USB.

Then run **update-initramfs -u** and reboot.

Comment: I disabled USB legacy in BIOS settings
Didn't find anything helpful in /etc/modprobe.d